# Convert date with string component to date time format in python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to convert the 'period' column in my dataframe in datetime format. The problem is, it has a string component. 
The period column has month wise values for instance "2019-MM-12, 2020-MM-01, 2020-MM-02, 2020-MM-03". Here, "03" means the month and not day.
Is there a way to convert it into proper date time format?

```py
data = {'Period':['2019-MM-10', '2019-MM-11', '2019-MM-12', '2020-MM-01'], 
        'Price' :[22000, 27000, 35000, 25000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
------------------------------
       Period  Price
0  2019-MM-10  22000
1  2019-MM-11  27000
2  2019-MM-12  35000
3  2020-MM-01  25000
```

Comment: Add code to your question which builds an example dataset (at least 3 values) and tell us what "proper date time format" means.

Comment: I have updated my question with example. What I mean by proper date time format is DD-MM-YY i.e., format = "%d%m%Y".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse your dates (which do not contain days, only years and months):

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df.Period, format="%Y-MM-%m")
```

Then if you want to go back to strings in another format:

```
dates.dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

The result is:

```
0    01-10-2019
1    01-11-2019
2    01-12-2019
3    01-01-2020
```